# For each table row / cell with specific class function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table. The table has some set of rows, each set containing 3 specific rows, and repeated downwards.

I want to have a variable `i` which should be incremented for each row (`<tr>`) having `class="nm"` or for each cell (`<td>`) having `class="zxcv"`. The incremented result value `i` may be alerted finally.

How can I do this using JavaScript with / without jQuery?

You can see [my JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/bmVrA/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get a count of `<tr class="nm">` and `<td class="zxcv">`, using jQuery, do this:

```
alert($('tr.nm, td.zxcv').length);
```

**EDIT:**

To loop through each element, do this:

```
$('tr.nm, td.zxcv').each(function(index, elem) { /* do something */ });
```

Comment: Here's your jsfiddle with the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/bmVrA/1/

Comment: no.. i need foreach.. i want to do something else with each row .. thats y.. :)

Comment: Gotcha. See my edit above. It's very similar to @hughes answer, but the selector is more specific and includes the `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I find your wording a bit unclear, but if you're trying to do something to each row with the class "nm" you could use the `.each()` function:

```
$('.nm').each(function(i,row) {
    //$(row) is now your .nm row
    alert(i);
});
```

Comment: i got it.. is it possible to do the same sing for each for each cell (<td>) having class="zxcv" ??

Comment: sure! You can just the selector `$('td.zxcv').each(...` instead.